# covariance matrix for three correlated variables

Tags: random-variable, covariance-matrix, random-vector

Suppose I have a covariance matrix for three random variable $X1,X2,X3$
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0.5& \rho
\\0.5&1&0.5
\\\rho&0.5&1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I know I can solve for valid values of $\rho \in [-0.5,1]$ to keep the covariance matrix positive semi-definite.

I know I can generate this distribution via Cholesky decomposition for any valid $\rho$ as in

```
n_obs = 200000
means = [0, 0, 0]
observations = np.vstack([np.random.normal(loc=mean, scale=1, size=n_obs)
                   for mean in means])
cor_matrix = np.array([[1,0.5,-0.49],
                       [0.5,1,0.5],
                       [-0.49,0.5,1]])
L = np.linalg.cholesky(cor_matrix)

print(np.cov(L.dot(observations)))
```

My question is what happens to the covariance between $X1,X3$ if I naively try to generate this distribution by forcing only the covariance between $X1,X2$ and $X2,X3$

```
X1 = np.random.normal(0,1,n_obs)
X2 = 1*(0.5*X1+np.sqrt(1-0.5**2)*np.random.normal(0,1,n_obs))
X3 = 1*(0.5*X2+np.sqrt(1-0.5**2)*np.random.normal(0,1,n_obs))
ob2 = np.vstack([X1,X2,X3])
```

I would have expected $\text{Cov}[X1,X3]$ to be drawn from some distribution across the feasible $\rho$ values, but when I execute this test the value is always 0.25 the middle of the range of possible $\rho$ values.

My question then is where is this extra structure coming from in the naive construction of the three correlated variables.

Comment: From your definitions of $X_1,X_2,X_3$ it follows that $\mbox{Cov}(X_1,X_3) = .25$.  This holds since $X_3 = .25 X_1 + u$, where $u$ denotes a normal variable independent of $X_1$.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. You should add it as an answer. Just because I asked a dumb question doesn't mean you shouldn't get credit for answering it.